# error when putting the views in a separate views.py file in flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am building a `flask application` and the main file of this application is named `app.py`

which is like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import Development
from flask_migrate import Migrate


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Development)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db) 


#@app.route('/')
#def index():
#   return "Blog Home"


from mod_admin import admin
from mod_users import users


app.register_blueprint(admin)
app.register_blueprint(users)
```

but i am trying to put all `views` in a file which is named `views.py` and looks like this:

```
from app import app


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Blog Home"
```

both `app.py` and `views.py` are in the same directory. when I run :

flask run

I will get the `url` and when I put it in the browser (tried a couple of them including `firefox and Chrom`), I will get `404 error`. however if I remove `views.py` and uncomment the view in the `app.py` it works perfectly and I can see the message on the browser.
do you know what could be the issue when I put the view in `views.py` and remove that from `app.py`?

Comment: Have you tried a relative import, changing the import statement to "from .app import app"?

Comment: @RobinUphoff : yes I tried that too but still the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app import from views and you need to use a view blueprint instead.

Views.py should look something like this:

```
bp = Blueprint('views', __name__, url_prefix='/', template_folder='./templates')

@bp.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "blog home"
```

and app.py should have the lines:

```
from views import bp
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```